# Map sorted by keys generated with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I need to serialize a class with a map so that the keys in the map are sorted in the json. So if there's a class

```
@Serializable
class Example(val map: Map<String, Int>)
```

and it's serialized with

```
val example = Example(mapOf("b" to 2, "a" to 1, "c" to 3))
println(Json.encodeToString(example))
```

then the resulting json should be

```
{
    "map": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3
    }
}
```

I tried to use `SortedMap` instead of `Map`, but that throws an exception:

> kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'TreeMap' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'SortedMap'

How can I get a sorted json using `kotlinx.serialization`?

(kotlin 1.4.0, kotlinx.serialization 1.0.0-RC)

Comment: Why do you need it to be sorted in the serialised form?  If you're only going to deserialise it, the order shouldn't matter.  And if you're going to use it somewhere else, then wouldn't it be better to do your own serialisation, instead of using the system's (which, if it's anything like standard Java serialisation, is intended only for deserialising again)?

Comment: @gidds - I need it not only for deserialization. This json that I generate can be also edited by other software. It's also committed to git. So if it's sorted, then the diff can be easily seen, and also it takes less space in git (it's quite a big json).

Json format is a standard, which actually makes it easy to be accessed by other tools and also see the changes manually. Actually, if I would only need it to be serialized internally, then it wouldn't matter much, and I could use unsorted map, or some custom serialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*
import kotlinx.serialization.builtins.*
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder

object SortedMapSerializer: KSerializer<Map<String, Int>> {
    private val mapSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Int.serializer())
    
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = mapSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Map<String, Int>) {
        mapSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.toSortedMap())
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Map<String, Int> {
        return mapSerializer.deserialize(decoder)
    }
}

@Serializable
class Example(
    @Serializable(with = SortedMapSerializer::class)
    val map: Map<String, Int>
)

fun main() {
    val example = Example(mapOf("b" to 2, "c" to 3, "a" to 1))
    println(Json.encodeToString(
        example
    ))
}
```

(Though it would be nice to have an answer for `Map<Serializable, Serializable>`